# Jquery UI Droppable and Resizable: Make dropped Div(with image) with Resizable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to add JQuery resizable function to my droppable (dropped) item in certain area (as a screen in this case). So far the drag and drop function runs well without problem. Anytime I drag an little box to the screen the screen will change the background color or the contents. You can see the jsFiddle here! http://jsfiddle.net/jengunfan/mgLTu/9/!  However, when I put the resizable('enable') script to order the droppable items it doesn't work at all and even disabled the original droppabe function.

The js script is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#block" ).draggable();


});



</script>


  <script>
  $(function() { 
  $(".sample").draggable({ 
  revert: true     
  });

   $("#screen").droppable({ 
      tolerance: 'touch', 
      over: function(event, ui){ 
       $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over'); },
         out: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out'); }, 
          drop: function(event, ui) {
              var idVal=$(ui.draggable).attr('id');
                console.log(idVal);
          if ( idVal=="sample6"){     
              $('#text').show();
          }

          else if (idVal=="sample1"){
            $("#screen").removeClass().addClass('bg1'); 
          }
          else if (idVal=="sample2"){
            $("#block").removeClass().addClass('bg2').resizable(); 
         }
           else if (idVal=="sample3"){
            $("#screen").removeClass().addClass('bg3'); 
          }
           else if (idVal=="sample4"){
            $("#block").removeClass().addClass('bg4'); 
            $("#sample4").resizable();
          }
           else if (idVal=="sample5"){
            $("#screen").removeClass().addClass('bg5'); 
          }


          }
        });
    }); 
  </script>
```

I also patch my html markups as follows:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header"><h2>JP-Box JQuery Plugin</h2></div>
<div id="screen" style="float:left">
<div id="block"  style="float:left; margin-left:50px; margin-top:100px;"></div>

<div id="text" class="draggable" ><textarea  style="border:hidden; color: yellow; background-color: transparent; z-index:1000px;">Text Here!</textarea>

</div>


</div>
<div id="display" style="position:relative;float:left">
<div id="memo"></div>

<div id="sample1" class="sample">
  <p><img src="images/grey.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" /> </p>
</div>
<div id="sample2" class="sample">
  <p><img src="images/smiley1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" /></p>
</div>
<div id="sample3" class="sample">
  <p><img src="images/blue.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" /></p>
</div>
<div id="sample4" class="sample">
  <p><img src="images/smiley2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" /></p>
</div>
<div id="sample5" class="sample">
  <p><img src="images/purple.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" /></p>
</div>
<div id="sample6" data-num="6" class="sample">
  <p><h3>Text Area</h3></p>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>



<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="footer">test</div>
```

Hope anyone can offer some possible solution or suggestion to this issue!